# Why am I getting this error when carrying out a basic mySQL search using JPA?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I am querying a my sql database. I have two tables:

Table 1: **BusinessAccount**

```
businessName (String);
businessAddress (String);
county (int); (county is the Foreign Key for countyId on table 2)
```

Table 2:  **County**

```
countyId (int);
countyName (String);
```

I am trying to return a list of all business accounts where the county=1. I am getting an error saying the following:

> You have attempted to set a value of type class `java.lang.Integer` for
>   parameter `CountyId` with expected type of class
>   `com.needABuilder.entities.County` from query string
>   `SELECT u FROM BusinessAccount u WHERE u.county=:CountyId`

I don't understand why I am getting this error as I am searching the BusinessAccount table for entries where the integer value county=1. Here is my code. Thanks for any help.

```
public List<BusinessAccount> searchContractors() {
    factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
    EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();   
    List<BusinessAccount> contractorList = new ArrayList<BusinessAccount>();

    em.getTransaction().begin();
    int countyId=1;
    Query myQuery = em.createQuery(
                    "SELECT u FROM BusinessAccount u WHERE u.county=:CountyId");
    myQuery.setParameter("CountyId", countyId);

    contractorList=myQuery.getResultList();
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();

    return contractorList;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message explains it all. `BusinessAccount.county` is of type `County`. It's not of type `Integer`. You can't compare a `County` with an `Integer`.

You can compare a County with another County, or an Integer with another Integer. So what you want (assuming `County.id` is of type `Integer` or `int`) is

```
select u from BusinessAccount u where u.county.id = :countyId
```

Comment: Thanks-that seems obvious now-I'm new to this but I understand what's going on now!